# Hide elements on navbar when changing screen's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently use Bootstrap v3.3.0 and i would like when user change the width of screen, the last elements of the navbar (LINKs before dropdown list) disappear and be added at the dropdown list.
Can I do that with Bootstrap or any JS library ?

Example of navbar : http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use the following approach:
Add them twice, so in the normal menu and in the dropdown. Then in CSS display or hide them when needed.

```
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    #item_link1
    {
        display:none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #item_link2
    {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Both solutions worked very well but i used the second method.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Jquery functions**

```
$(window).on("orientationchange load resize", function () {
     var width = $(document).width();
     if(width<765){
          // $("#elementID").hide();
          //  code for other elements hide stuff
     }
     else if(width>765){
          // for show iamges
     }
});
```