# Collapse bootstrap's navbar symbols to menu one by one.

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm have a bootstrap's navbar in my page.

How can I make a navbar that will **never** warp the icons, but will add them one by one into a sub-menu in a button.
(And if possible - to make the symbols be removed from left to right, meaning that the first symbol to disappear will be the one to the furthest to the left)

Comment: This is nearly impossible to imagine without a working HTML/CSS example and at best a picture of what you have/what you need !

Comment: If someone knows how to do it, I think it will be easier for him/her to write a simple example I can use, than to dig my code and change the things. If posting a simple example of a navbar will help, I can do so, but I think there are enough out there.

Comment: I think this will help you do this : [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26756158/hide-elements-on-navbar-when-changing-screens-width) , you just need to specify the elements from the left in your case (for the css answer) , and for the jquery one, you need to use the ids of the links from left to right. I hope this'll be helpful for you.

Comment: It is a working solution, but I was hoping for something a bit more general, so I don't need to define a width for each of the elements in my navbar.